# Factories, constructors and generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

Let's say I have a factory ressembling this:

```
public static class BusinessObjectFactory
{
   public static T Create<T>(int objectId) where T : BusinessObject, new()
    {
        var dataSource = DataLayer.DataSources.Repository.Get<T>();
        var serializer = DataLayer.Serializers.Repository.Get<T>();

        var businessObject = new T {ObjectId = objectId, DataSource = dataSource, Serializer = serializer};

        return businessObject;
    }
}
```

This works provided I have public accessors for ObjectId, DataSource and Serializer.

I would rather specify these arguments in my type T constructor, knowing that
T is constrained as a BusinessObject and a BusinessObject has that kind of 
constructor.

I know that I could replace my call to new T with something like this:

```
var businessObject = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), objectId, dataSource, serializer);
```

But what is the technical reason why my T constructor must be parameterless? I feel there is something I don't understand about generics. I've seen several questions floating around on SO related to that topic but no answer that really enlightened me.

Comment: There's no way the compiler can verify (or enforce) that nobody writes a class that derives from `BusinessObject` but does not have a constructor that takes the three arguments `ObjectId,DataSource,Serializer`. Then that class could be used as `T` above. There's no syntax for a generic constraint to constrain to types that have the correct three-parameter constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are *compile-time* artifacts. That means that at *compile-time* there will be new generated suitable class.

At *compile time* the parameter of the ctor, could not be yet identified (if it's not a constant).

That's why you have to have an "empty" ctor, that CLR is able to contsuct your type's object.

Comment: Thanks. That is the explanation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a `new()` constraint, specifying that there is a parameter-less constructor. There is no way to specify that that type needs a `T(ObjectId, DataSource, Serializer)` constructor. Not in the generics-constraints and not in an interface or baseclass.